# React Native Android - Pop a screen after push notification while the phone is locked

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, lockscreen

We are working on VoIP client application on react-native.

One feature of the app is incoming call while the app is in the background or totally terminated. We achieve this kind of functionality by using push notifications - when the app receives push notification, it registers to the sip(VoIP) server and pop up an incoming call screen. (we use wix-navigation as our navigation module and work with screens https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

the problem we face now is popping the incoming call screen while the phone is locked. we know the app receives the push notification for sure, but the same logic that works and pop the screen when the phone is unlocked, doesn't work in case the phone is locked.

I've come across this tutorial: https://belka.us/en/callkit-android-react-native/
which implement something similar but with native code.
Is there other way to achieve my goal?

Thank you very much!